# Convert Curl command line in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rest-client, httparty

This is my curl command which works nicely in Command line :

```
curl --data @order_new.json \
     -H "X-Augury-Token:My_token_goes_here" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     http://staging.hub.spreecommerce.com/api/stores/store_id_goes_here/messages
```

I need to implement the same in rails using any sort of Gem, Tried with HTTParty /rest_client / spree-api-client, but something wrong here :

```
require 'httparty'

result = HTTParty.post(
        "http://staging.hub.spreecommerce.com/api/stores/52eb347f755b1c97e900001e/messages",
        :body => JSON.parse(File.read("order_new.json")),
        :header => {
           "X-Augury-Token" => "UjjKsdxbrwjpAPx9Hiw4",
           "Content-Type" => "application/json" 
        }
)
```

But I am getting Error,

```
"The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)"
```

I need rails equivalent of above curl command, use of spree-api-client gem will be much helpful.

Comment: Curl is doing a get request and http party a post request.

Comment: I doubt it @andHapp, the curl command sends along a `--data` parameter, so it should be a POST request, not a GET request.

Comment: Ohh right..sorry missed that!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use the `Spree::API::Client`, could you post the results of your findings? Could you evaluate the output of the following commands and post back:

```
client = Spree::API::Client.new('http://staging.hub.spreecommerce.com/api/', 'UjjKsdxbrwjpAPx9Hiw4')
client.products.inspect
```

Comment: I have already seen such in github link, But how I can pass the -header, -data attributes just like curl is doing.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. This gem is not a replacement for the curl command, it's a client that you can use to communicate with spree. If you're trying to create an order, you should be able to do that with `client.create_order(data)`. Take a look at the code to understand what is happening: https://github.com/andrew/spree-api-client/blob/master/lib/spree-api-client.rb, https://github.com/andrew/spree-api-client/blob/master/lib/spree-api-client/connection.rb and https://github.com/andrew/spree-api-client/blob/master/lib/spree-api-client/orders.rb

Comment: Yes, I got your point, using client.create_order(data), we can create_order in our store front (spree), but it does not pass any message to hub explicitly. 
 but  as per my question, I need to pass similar notification message to my hub (staging.hub.spreecommerce.com/) !  :)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I'm unfamiliar with the Spreecommerce hub, but I've looked into it. Isn't this simply what you're looking for? https://github.com/spree/spree_hub_connector

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'httparty'

result = HTTParty.post(
        "http://staging.hub.spreecommerce.com/api/stores/52eb347f755b1c97e900001e/messages",
        :body => @order.to_json,
        :header => {
           "X-Augury-Token" => "UjjKsdxbrwjpAPx9Hiw4",
           "Content-Type" => "application/json" 
        }
)
```

Don't parse json while passing to HTTParty body

Comment: GOT ERROR: NoMethodError: undefined method `json' for nil:NilClass

Let's forget about adding .json file as input, Can We pass an object in :body section ?  Just like :body => Order.last ?

Comment: you have to pass json in body , so load order in \@order and write \@order.to_json